# how to access control name in .cs file wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help how to access the control name in `.cs` file as my `xaml` shows below

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Select what you want to keep in this order for Invoicing purpose." FontFamily="TimesNewRoman" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text=""></TextBlock>
            <CheckBox                 
                Visibility="Visible"
                Name="selectAll"
```

Comment: Please show what you have previously tried

Comment: Set `x:Name="selectAll"` in XAML and use `selectAll` in code later

Comment: Are you trying to use controlName elsewhere in your XAML, in the codebehind for that Window/UserControl/whatever, or somewhere else such as a ViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give controls a name with `x:Name` like

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="Select what you want to keep in this order for Invoicing purpose." FontFamily="TimesNewRoman" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
```

and then access it in code later like

```
this.myTextBlock.Text = "Bla"
```

Be aware that the controls are instantiated in the `InitializeComponent();` call in the constructor so you can't reference them beforehand, only after that call.